# setInterval(function, timer) become to infinite loop when click Enter key

Tags: javascript, java, spring, performance, spring-mvc

I have my set interval function and its working fine, **but sometimes after setintervel trigged and I pressed Enter key some 4 to 5 times** and my interval become infinite. can any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

code: 
/*one of the js file*/

```
 var intervaltime=setInterval(functionname(), 1000);
    functionname()
    {
    if(pageloaded== "true"){  //pageloaded is coming from one JSP when I click that page.jsp
            clearInterval(intervaltime);
            }
    }
**//page.jps**
<input type="hidden" value="true" id="pageloaded" name="pageloaded" />
```

page.jsp: 
          init method I added the hidden variable and to set the value of

Comment: `var salestabinterval=setInterval(function(), 1000);` will throw a SyntaxError

Comment: can you please elaborate, how it will throw an error and if there any other way to handle that error

Comment: Because that's not how you call and declare a function. Hit F12 to see the Developer Console, there you can see the error messages.

Comment: question updated last clear is not in code. its wrongly added can you check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the setInterval Method needs a function as first parameter, not "function()" .
For example :

```js
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("hello");
}, 1000);
```

You can also use the following syntaxe to declare your function ouside the timer :

```js
function yourfunc() {
    // ...
}
setInterval(yourfunc, 1000);
```

Also, I think that what you are trying to do is to stop something when your input is clicked or when your page is loaded. If so, the timer is not a good way to do that. You should use an event listener instead.

I hope it helped